# Automatic outlier removal in multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression, outliers

I know that most statisticians are against removing outliers unless one carefully looks at the data, however there might be applications where multiple models are automatically generated and hence looking at the data is not possible, so the process needs to be automated. When outliers are present because of errors in measurement, these should be probably removed. So what would be the recommended way of doing such a removal for outliers in the dependent variable with typically skewed distribution whose range is not a priori known?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be *very* leery of any regression where "looking at the data is not possible".  I wouldn't trust the results and I wouldn't base any big decisions on the results.  You have to look at the data.

But, if you *have* to do this (say, your boss tells you to do it or you are fired) and you suspect outliers, then what I would do is not use OLS regression at all, but rather use a method that is resistant to the effect of outliers.  Examples are robust regression and quantile regression.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. In my scenario, hundreds of models need to be generated frequently (e.g. daily), I will go with what you mention. Is it possible to combine regularization with such robust regression methods (e.g. L1, L2)?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that. It probably depends on the method. But you can automate the process of identifying points that _might_ be mistakes.

Comment: Because $L^2$ normalization (aka "ridge regression") can be formulated as an OLS problem, it would be possible to combine that with robust regression methods such as IWLS.  I have recently completed software that every month needs to perform thousands of regressions involving tens of thousands of observations with hundreds of variables each. It's just not possible to look closely at them all.  Therefore the software works hard to identify outliers in any way it can. It reports them but it *also* proceeds with the analysis (removing severe outliers). It combines IWLS and ElasticNet procedures.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice, I will do my best and see what I can get